# Save(Excel,CSV,PDF) and Copy is not working in Datatable Tools

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using data table tool from https://www.datatables.net/
The Print is working fine but Save and Copy is not working.
Here is My **JS code**.

```
// datatables table tools
                $('#datatablestools').dataTable({
                    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "aButtons": [
                            "copy",
                            "print",
                            {
                                "sExtends":    "collection",
                                "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                                "aButtons":    [ 
                                    "xls", 
                                    "csv",
                                    {
                                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                                        "sPdfMessage": "Your custom message would go here."
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "sSwfPath": "js/datatables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you create the folder and include swf file correctly?

According to your code, your swf file must be under the folder path "**js/datatables/swf/**".

Answer (score 0):

One could also try excluding "sSwfPath" from the initialization and add the following code:

```
TableTools.DEFAULTS.sSwfPath = "your path";
// mine was TableTools.DEFAULTS.sSwfPath = "<?php echo $this->basePath() ?>/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf";
```